# RewriteRule with 2 values

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

url : http://siteexample.tld/index.php?a=profile&u=johndoe
I am trying to change this url to look like `siteexample.tld/profile/johndoe`
if if a=groups then `siteexample.tld/groups/nameofgroup` etc...

this is my htaccess so far

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not keeping it simple? (`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?a=$1&q=$2 [L]`)

Comment: would that work for what im trying to do ?

Comment: Yes. It limits to two captures which can be sent off to the two parameters...